# Is it better to pass references down a chain or to use public static variables

Tags: c#, xna

Say we have a Game class.

The game class needs to pass down a reference to it's spritebatch. That is, the class calls a method passing it, and that method in turn passes it to other  methods, until it is finally used.

Is this bad for performance? Is it better to just use statics?

I see one obvious disadvantage of statics though, being unable to make duplicate functionality in the same application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not easy to answer your question as you have not specifically mentioned the requirement but generally i can give you some advice.

1. **Always consider encapsulation**: Do not expose the properties if they are not used else where.
2. **Performance** :For reference types, there is no any performance penalty, as they are already a reference type.but if your type is a value type then there will be a very small performance penalty.

So there is a Design or Performance trade off exists, Unless your method is called millions of times, you never have to think about **public static** property.

Answer (score 1):

There are *cons* and *pros* like in everything.

Is this is a *good* or *bad* from performance point of view, depends on how computational intensive and how often used that code inside your game.

So here are my considerations on subject.

Passing like parameter:

*Cons* : passing more variable on stack, to push it into the function call.It's very fast, but again, it depends *how* the code you're talking about is used, so absence of it *can* bring some benefits, that's why inserted this point in cons.

*Pros* : you esplicitly manifest that the function on top of calling stack needs that parameter for *read and/or write*, so one looking on that code could easily imagine semantic dependencies of your calls.

Use like static:

Cons : There is no clear evidence (if not via direct knowledge or good written documentation) what parameters would or could affect the calculus inside that functions.

Pros : You don't pass it on the stack for all functions in chain.

I would personally recommend: use it like a parameter, because this clearly manifests what calling code depends on and *even if there would be some measurable performance drawback*, most probably it will not be relevant in your case. But again, as Rico Mariani always suggests: *measure*, *measure*, *measure*...

Answer (score 0):

Statics is mostly not the best way. Because if later one you want to make multiple instances you might be in trouble.

Of course passing references cost a bit of performance, but depending on the amount of creation of instances it will matter more or less. Unless you are creating millions of objects every small amount of time it might be an issue.

Comment: If it is a reference type there is no any performance penalty, as they are already a reference type.